# For loop to create button array not displaying properly in JPanel

Tags: java, arrays, swing, layout, layout-manager

So i'm creating an array of buttons that is supposed to display and 8,8 grid, instead it displays very small buttons spreading across the window (31 buttons in a row for two rows then two more buttons on the third). If I replace:

```
gamePanel1.add(buttons[a][b]);
```

with:

```
 frame.add(buttons[a][b]);
```

... it display correctly but when initialising the array, I have to resize the window to see the buttons as it does not fit to contents.

Here is the code to create the buttons:

```
contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());    
JPanel gamePanel1 = new JPanel();


buttons = new JButton[boardsize][boardsize];
mineBoard = new int[9][9];
for (int a = 0; a < boardsize; a++) 
    for (int b = 0; b < boardsize; b++) {
        buttons[a][b] = new JButton("");
        buttons[a][b].setBounds(30+gridsize*a,30+gridsize*b,gridsize,gridsize);
        gamePanel1.add(buttons[a][b]);
        buttons[a][b].addMouseListener(new MouseListener(a,b));
        setx(a);
        sety(b);
        settried(false);
        setmine(false);

    }


    contentPane.add(gamePanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Can anyone tell me how I might fix this or show me how with this code I may use a different layout - i tried grid layout for the buttons but could not get it working at all.

Comment: missing there code line gamePanel1.setLayout...., described issue talking about standards from default LayoutManager implemented in API for JPanel

Comment: I have currently contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); I will add this into the question.

Comment: Use GridLayout on `gamePanel1`, avoid use of set bounds on button

Comment: I removed the set bounds and I'm playing around with gridLayout, it does not display.  What should i use for the parameters? I am currently using: 
    gamePanel1.setLayout(newGridLayout(boardsize,boardsize,boardsize,boardsize));

Comment: You most likely don't want to set the gaps to `boardsize`. Start with just `new GridLayout(boardsize, boardsize)`. Are you perhaps showing the window before the contents are added? You should add all the contents, call `frame.pack()`, and only after then call `frame.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: frame.pack() and frame.setVisible(true); are the last thing called  so i'm not sure its that.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a Panel as:

```
JPanel panel=new JPanel();
```

Then set the layout as

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
```

Then using a for loop create and add the buttons and the buttons will be displayed in eight by eight grid. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this as-is but it did not work, however, small amendment:
JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(boardsize, boardsize))
and it worked perfectly, thanks. I used the panel as a container.

Comment: You are welcome.I think it is the same both ways and when i tried,the both the ways worked.Anyways, glad it worked for you.